# error: return super().__getattribute__(attr)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I try to run the following script from the tutorial (https://youtu.be/bZUTiAJ1Tuc). While I try to execute a grid by clicking on a respective button panel I get the following error message

> "...line 48
> C/....Blender Foundation/...Modules/bpy.types.py line 721 return super().**getattribute**(attr).

> MESH_OT_monkey_grid has not attribute count_x

I basically copied the script in the tutorial... and looked for some info about the getattribute function, didn't help much
Any input, tip on how to overcome this issue?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Monkeys Add-on",
    "author": "Yariv Friedman",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 91, 0),
    "location": "Operator Search",
    "description": "Monkey Exemple Add-on",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh"
}

import bpy


class MESH_OT_monkey_grid(bpy.types.Operator):

    """Let's spread some joy"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.monkey_grid"
    bl_label = "Monkey Grid"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    count_x: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="X",
        description="number of Monkeys in the X direction",
        default=3,
        min=1, soft_max=9,
    )
    count_y: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Y",
        description="number of Monkeys in the Y direction",
        default=2,
        min=1, soft_max=10,
    )
    size: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Size",
        description="Size of each monkey",
        default=0.5,
        min=0, soft_max=1,
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        for idx in range(self.count_x * self.count_y):
            x = idx%self.count_X
            y = idx//self.count_y
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(
                size=self.size,
                location=(x, y, 1))

        return {'FINISHED'}


class VIEW3D_PT_monkey_grid(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Monkeys"
    bl_label = "Grid"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator('mesh.monkey_grid',
            text='Default Grid',
            icon='MONKEY')
        props = self.layout.operator('mesh.monkey_grid',
            text='Big Grid',
            icon='MONKEY')
        props.count_x = 10
        props.count_y = 10
        props.size = 0.8

def register():

    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_monkey_grid)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_monkey_grid)


def unregister():

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_monkey_grid)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_monkey_grid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: There is a small typo -> `x = idx%self.count_X` should be `x = idx%self.count_x` (line 43)

Comment: ..or to be PEP8 pedantic  `idx % self.count_x`  always wrap operators with spaces. `a + b`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a basic python syntax error  (resolved in comments.)

Comment: Thanks, for both clarifications. The problem was resolved. I don't have enough credits to close this question.